# is there a different ways to check deque empty in python

Tags: python, deque

Are they the same thing????

```
while len(deque)>0:
    deque.popleft()

while deque:
   deque.popleft()
```

so basically these two condition loops can avoid poping from empty queue?

Comment: Do you mean `while len(deque) > 0:`?  Otherwise the answer is no, the first one will raise `IndexError: pop from an empty deque` when it runs out of elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're the same, but PEP 8 prefers the second version.  I'm not convinced that it's always easier to read though, so use your own judgement.

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations

> For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false.
>
> ```
> Yes: if not seq:
>      if seq:
>
> No: if len(seq)
>     if not len(seq)
> ```

Comment: Thankyou, it definitely make my codes look better!!! and I can eventually find the bug!!